# 'Thank You - Your transaction has been successful' popup - what part of the Storekit code triggers it?

Tags: ios, swift2, in-app-purchase

I am trying to intercept/delay the App Store transaction successful pop-up that a transaction was successful until AFTER I get hold of the receipt so that I can run some validation on receipt id, product id etc.

However, I cannot seem to find the bit of code (I assume it is something in the PaymentQueue) that actually triggers it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .Purchased:
                    println("Product Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break;
                case .Failed:
                    println("Purchased Failed");
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break;
                    // case .Restored:
                    //[self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: Hmmm. My testing shows that the message is triggered before 'entering' this function. As soon as the message appears  this code starts execution.

Comment: what exactly this answer mean? how to delay showing alert popup until validation receipt has been finished?

Comment: The answer did not answer my question - it just shows the known process. I am/was trying to delay the pop-up until receipt validation is done. Unfortunately, from what I can gather, if the response from app store hits your device as oppose to your own 'in-app-purchase server' which in turn send the confirm to the device, you have no control over this pop up. Any suggestion would be welcome!